# Calling Webservice From AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am calling web-service from AngularJS using this code:

```
$http({
    url: "DBService.asmx/GetRG_Users",
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    data: '',
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

But I am only able to access limited number of rows from Service. Once I tried to get all rows it will throw:

> 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: You've told us that you're having a server side problem (500 error), yet given us no information about the server side. The question is currently unanswerable.

Comment: It means that you don't use API properly. Nothing that anyone but you can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Its a server side implementation. You cannot retrieve huge amount of response from the server using http request. You need to set the max size as

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using below information in config

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
       <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>           
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```